# dropna=True behaviour in pandas.DataFrame.groupby and pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm trying to inspect the behaviour of the `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` and `pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table` methods and I've come up to this difference which I can't explain by myself.

It seems that the specification of `dropna=True` (default for both) has different consequences in the two cases, which might be somehow enforced by the different descriptions which are given within the docs.

For [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot-table):

> dropna: bool, default True
>
> ***Do not include columns whose entries are all NaN.***

For [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

> dropna: bool, default True
>
> ***If True, and if group keys contain NA values, NA values together with row/column will be dropped. If False, NA values will also be treated as the key in groups.***

This said, while I can totally understand the description given for the `.pivot_table()` method looking at the example I'll show in a while, I can't get through the nuances of the `dropna` behaviour in `.groupby()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'age': [31, np.nan, 28, 22, 54, np.nan, 49, 60, 25, np.nan],
    'country_live': ['Italy', 'Spain', 'Italy', 'Spain', 'France', 'Italy', 'Spain', 'Spain', 'France', 'Spain'],
    'employment_status': ['Fully employed by a company / organization', 'Partially employed by a company / organization',
    'Working student', 'Working student', 'Fully employed by a company / organization', 'Partially employed by a company / organization',
    'Fully employed by a company / organization', 'Fully employed by a company / organization', 'Working student',
    'Partially employed by a company / organization']
    },
)

df = df.assign(age=lambda t: t['age'].astype('Int64'), \
    country_live=lambda t: t['country_live'].astype('category'), \
    employment_status=lambda t: t['employment_status'].astype('category'))
```

With `.pivot_table()`:

```
df.pivot_table(index='country_live', columns='employment_status', values='age', aggfunc='mean', dropna=True)
```

[image]

With `.groupby()` I'd instead get (while expecting the same result obtained above):

```
df.groupby(by=['country_live', 'employment_status'], dropna=True)['age'] \
    .mean() \
    .unstack()
```

[image]

Can someone explain the reason(s) why the two do not work the same (thus implicitly explaining the behaviour of `dropna` in `.groupby()`)?

Comment: *if group keys contain NA values, NA values together with row/column will be dropped* it means that if you do `df.groupby('col1')` and `col1` contains NA value, these will be ignored. In your example, the NA values only concern `age` and impact the `mean` calculation.

Comment: @Tranbi thank you, I understand! Therefore, just a different behaviour; I thought I could have got to the same result by only specifying `dropna=True` in `.groupby()`.

Comment: @Tranbi sorry again, I think I quite get your point, but I still can't understand why if I add a NA in group key `country_live` (as in the example of the answer) and I specify `dropna=False`, I don't get a new group with NAs. Can you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replying to your comment here since code formatting is a pain in comments.

I don't know exactly how you tried `dropna=False` for `groupby`, but running the following code will show the group with `nan` value for `country_live`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'age': [31, np.nan, 28, 22, 54, np.nan, 49, 60, 25, np.nan],
    'country_live': ['Italy', pd.NA, 'Italy', 'Spain', 'France', 'Italy', 'Spain', 'Spain', 'France', 'Spain'],
    'employment_status': ['Fully employed by a company / organization', 'Partially employed by a company / organization',
    'Working student', 'Working student', 'Fully employed by a company / organization', 'Partially employed by a company / organization',
    'Fully employed by a company / organization', 'Fully employed by a company / organization', 'Working student',
    'Partially employed by a company / organization']
    },
)

df = df.assign(age=lambda t: t['age'].astype('Int64'), \
    country_live=lambda t: t['country_live'].astype('category'), \
    employment_status=lambda t: t['employment_status'].astype('category'))

for gp, sub_df in df.groupby(by=['country_live', 'employment_status'], dropna=False):
    print(gp, sub_df, "\n", sep="\n")
```

Output (see last lines):

```
('France', 'Fully employed by a company / organization')
   age country_live                           employment_status
4   54       France  Fully employed by a company / organization


('France', 'Working student')
   age country_live employment_status
8   25       France   Working student


('Italy', 'Fully employed by a company / organization')
   age country_live                           employment_status
0   31        Italy  Fully employed by a company / organization


('Italy', 'Partially employed by a company / organization')
    age country_live                               employment_status
5  <NA>        Italy  Partially employed by a company / organization


('Italy', 'Working student')
   age country_live employment_status
2   28        Italy   Working student


('Spain', 'Fully employed by a company / organization')
   age country_live                           employment_status
6   49        Spain  Fully employed by a company / organization
7   60        Spain  Fully employed by a company / organization


('Spain', 'Partially employed by a company / organization')
    age country_live                               employment_status
9  <NA>        Spain  Partially employed by a company / organization


('Spain', 'Working student')
   age country_live employment_status
3   22        Spain   Working student


(nan, 'Partially employed by a company / organization')
    age country_live                               employment_status
1  <NA>          NaN  Partially employed by a company / organization
```

Respectively, the `nan` group will be ignored if you set `dropna=True`

Comment: thanks, perhaps there is some mess with packages versions as running your code I exactly get the groups you're obtaining, but the last one (last group for me is `('Spain', 'Working student')`. I'll try to dig in further

Comment: For whom it might be helpful, this bug effectively exists in `pandas` version `1.5.1` as reported in https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.5.1.html#behavior-of-groupby-with-categorical-groupers-gh48645. It was present as well in versions < `1.5` and fixed in version `1.5.0` at the cost of introducing a regression when passing `observed=False` (together with `dropna=False`). Eventually, the `dropna=False` bug was reintroduced to fix the other in version `1.5.1`.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that for `.groupby()` the `dropna=True` refers to the groups you are creating, NOT to the values. In fact if you add a row to your `df`:

```
row = {'age':50,'country_live':np.nan,'employment_status':'Partially employed by a company / organization'}

df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```

the pivot table does not change the output changing the bool of `dropna` (you don't have the `nan` group in the index.

The situation changes in the groupby:
With `dropna=True` you have the same result you obtained, with `dropna=False`, the `nan` group is added

Comment: thank you for your answer. I think I now understand the fact that _for `.groupby()` the `.dropna=True` refers to the groups and not to the values_, though I can't follow your example. With `.pivot_table()` I do see a change in specifying `.dropna=True` or `.dropna=False` (column disappears in the first case, full column
 with NA in the second case; in neither case the new group with nan is created, which I don't totally get). With `.groupby()` actually nothing changes with the two specifications, while I would have expected the nan group to be added).Can u please elaborate more?

Comment: What you say is right. What I'm saying is that adding a `nan` value in a column you are grouping by does not add that row in the `pivot_table` method (since the `dropna` is referred to the `values`). Otoh, with `groupby` the `nan` group is added for `dropna=False`, since in this operation also groups formed by `nan` values are retained. The difference lies in the meaning of `dropna`. Two equal args in two different methods don't translate into two equal behaviours. The `dropna` in `pivot_table` refers to VALUES, while the one in `groupby` refers to GROUPS you are generating